open3d is not treating the origin of a mesh as I would expect
I have a .glb file to which I have changed the origin in blender, when I stay within blender everything works as it should but when I try to open the same mesh within open3d it seems to re-centre the object to the old origin or otherwise not load the change that has taken place.
mesh = o3d.io.read_triangle_mesh("./prove/mesh.glb")

o3d.visualization.draw_geometries([mesh])

this is a simplified code for displaying the object, and again, going to display the origin, it is shifted

you speak of OpenCV but you don't show any code using it. I just see Open3D code in your question (different from OpenCV). if you truly mean "OpenCV", not "Open3D", I'm sorry for editing your question. the edit makes sense in context.

yes sorry it was a typo
